# How to grant permissions to spreadsheet via web app

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a web app that I have created within my organization where the user will click a row and it will update an inventory spreadsheet (see below). If someone changes the status of an item from "Available" to "Checked Out", then it will also log a string in one of the tabs on the spreadsheet such as "Joe Shmoe checked out iPad 1 on 7/19/2023." However, because I am using the AdminDirectory permissions in order to get the user's name, I need the user to approve additional permissions:

```
function updateData(row, column, newData, userEmail, item) {

  // Update sheet with status
  const cell = inventorySheet.getRange(row, column);
  cell.setValue(newData);

  // Update log
    const userName = (email) => {
    const method = AdminDirectory.Users.get(email, {viewType:'domain_public'});
    const fullname = method.name.fullName;
    return fullname;    
  }

  const logNoteCheckIN = `${userName(userEmail)} checked ${item} back in at ${dateTime()[1]} hours on ${dateTime()[0]}`
  logSheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(logNoteCheckIN)

};
```

However, the function and button I have set up for this are not working:

```
<button id="reauth">Reauthorize</button>
<script>
  $('#reauth').click(function() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(url) {
      window.open(url, '_blank');
    }).reauthorize();
  });
</script>
```

```
function reauthorize() {
  const authInfo = ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL);
  const url = authInfo.getAuthorizationUrl();
  return url;
};
```

How can I make this work?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you publish the Web App to execute as yourself or as the user accessing the web app? If you run it under yourself, then you shouldn't run into any auth issues (except for the very first time you run the code).

Comment: Ah gotcha, I was mostly testing this in the dev environment, so I will try publishing this to see how it works.

Comment: Makes sense, if you are able to resolve this on your own, feel free to post an answer to your question so others can see it if they run into a similar issue.

Comment: Is your concern resolved?

Comment: Not yet, I am still working on testing out the suggestion. I will close it out once it is done.

Comment: If your issue is resolved please post the solution as an answer. This is to let the community know with the same concern that this has been settled.

Comment: Unfortunately after several attempts the issue is still not resolved

Comment: Can you please share a sample sheet that you are working on with working code so that I can replicate your concern.

Comment: Hey Twilight, I apologize for delays on my end. I'm glad I'm not the only one with this issue - Just got swamped at work but I will update what I have now by tomorrow evening. Hopefully we can both come to a solution!